# php script unable to create tab or new line in excel

Tags: php, header, phpexcel

i have this code to make excel file

```
header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls" );
echo "test".chr(14)."test"."\t"."test".'<br>';
echo "test"."\t"."test"."\t"."test".PHP_EOL;
echo "test"."\t"."test"."\t"."test".PHP_EOL;
echo "test"."\t"."test"."\t"."test"."\n";
```

This code won't create tab or new line on excel file. It works in live server, but doesn't work properly in localhost. I tried **"\t" ,chr(13), chr(14), PHP_EOL** but it does't work too. It will make new line if I wii used ** `<br>` **
Can you help me to fix this please. Thank you

Comment: what do you really want to do? just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

After this header

```
header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls" );
```

try adding these header

```
header("Pragme: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```